# Unique content for each instance of a page app?

Tags: facebook, tabs

So I have a canvas app that allows a user to create content to be displayed in a page tab. User input is saved in an xml file. The xml file is named with the userid, example: `12345678.xml`.

I also have a page app that uses PHP simpleXML to load and display content from the xml file

So, if I created content via the canvas app, I can create a page tab app and point it at `MYPAGEAPPDOMAIN/index.php?uid=12345678` and use the passed uid variable to load the proper xml file, and display the content I created under that uid. I've tested all this and it works fine.

The problem is, that each user would have to manually create their own page tab app, with the url containing their user id to display the correct content. I could provide instructions and say "here's how your url should look" but I'd really like to simply let them click "add this to my page."

As far as I can tell from other questions I've found, everyone who adds the page will display content from the url specified in the page app basic settings. So there's no way to have Jim's iframe load `index.php?uid=12345678` and Jenny's iframe load `index.php?uid=87654321`.

Is there any way, when a page tab is loaded, to get the user id of the person who installed it? (Get the admin ID for the page?)

Or is there any other way to let each instance of my page tab app display the proper content for it's location?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find out what Page has installed my Facebook Canvas App?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5587784/how-can-i-find-out-what-page-has-installed-my-facebook-canvas-app)

Comment: I had considered using the page id for the file name rather than the user id, but that would mean they would have to have installed the page app before the file is created. Otherwise I'd have no way of knowing where they'll be installing it.

Comment: If I could use the page id to get the user id of that page's admin, perhaps that could work? But what about multiple admins..

Comment: But the content is displayed on a per-app basis, not per-user - the signed request will also tell you if the current user (regardless of their authorising your app) is an admin of the current page

Comment: Knowing whether the user viewing the page is the admin or not doesn't help me, as I want anyone who visits the page to see the content. I just want to make sure the content is the content that admin created, not the content someone else created.

Comment: As an example, if person A creates content and installs the tab on three pages he owns, it should show the same content on each of those pages. But if person B creates content and installs the tab on his page it will show his content, not person A's.

Comment: If the user has authorised your app, you'll get their uid in the signed_request. If they haven't, you'll still have the page id and whether the current user is an admin. If you don't trust 'any admin' of the page not to break another admin's edits, make the page admins authorise your app and do the authentication based on their user ID

Comment: It's not a question of authorization... I'm not talking about creating or editing content, just displaying it.

Comment: Same answer, then. Use the data facebook sends to your app to determine whether or not to display certain content. If you need the user ID, you'll need them to authorise your app

Comment: Solution: Not what I was looking for but an improvement. Handle the content creation on a separate page within the tab app available only to admins. That way, content is created on the page so the page ID will be available at the time of creation. Then we can use the page ID to reference the content rather than a user ID.